# How to print variable name instead of its value shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting

Below is my program, `a.sh` :

```
A=10 B=20 C=0 D=1

for var in {A,B,C,D}
do
    if [ $var = 0 ]
    then
        echo "$var value is 0"
    else
        echo "Ok" 
    fi
done
```

Result is :

```
# sh a.sh

Ok
Ok
0 value is 0   <==== Instead of this I want  "C value is 0"
Ok
```

How can we do this ?

Comment: I would not recommend you develop shell scripts as root.

Comment: I don't see any way that script could be generating that output.

Answer (score 6):

With `bash`:

```
A=10
B=20
C=0
D=1

for var in A B C D; do
    if [ ${!var} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$var value is 0"
    else
        echo "Ok"
    fi
done
```

Use `-eq` to compare integer values (or use `(( ${!var} == 0 ))` or `(( !${!var} ))` which is the same thing), and use `${!var}` to get the value of the variable whose name is stored in the variable `var`.

Or, a bit neater but essentially the same (still in `bash`):

```
for var in A B C D E; do
    case ${!var} in
        0) printf '%s value is 0\n' "$var" ;;
        *) echo 'Ok' ;;
    esac
done
```

This treats the values as strings, not as integers.